# implicit constructor not recognized

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to figure out why the compiler does not deduce that it should use the string constructor of `Obj`.

Shouldn't implicit construction be enabled for this case? (i pass const reference string and const reference Obj)
Isn't that the entire idea of implicit construction? what am i missing here?

```
class Obj
{
public:
    Obj(const std::string& str)
    {

    }

    void operator+=(const Obj& other)
    {
        cout << "operator+=" << endl;
    }

    Obj& operator++()
    {
        operator +=("something"); // error
        return *this;
    }
};
```

i'm compiling with gcc 4.8.2,
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion from the string literal `"something"` to `Obj` would require *two* user-defined conversions: one from the string literal to an `std::string`, and one from `std::string` to `Obj` using your constructor. Implicit conversion sequences are limited to containing only one user-defined conversion.

The best way to solve this problem is to add another constructor that takes a C string,

```
Obj(const char* str)
```

If you don't want to add such a constructor and you want to perform this conversion just once, you could:

1. Write `operator+=(std::string("something"))` (perform the first conversion explicitly)
2. (C++14) Write `operator+=("something"s)`, which uses the new user-defined literal suffix `s` to construct `std::string`

Answer (score 2):

You aren't allowed more than one user defined conversion. You have two, `char*` to `std::string`, and `std::string` to `Obj`. You can fix this by passing an `std::string` to your `operator+=`:

```
Obj& operator++()
{
    operator +=(std::string("something"));
    return *this;
}
```

Alternatively, you can add an implicit constructor that takes a `const char*`"

```
Obj(const char* str)
```